# ERROR: The GPU does not support this version of OpenGL ES, try an older version in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

```
I/Adreno  (21484): ERROR: The GPU does not support this version of OpenGL ES, try an older version
    D/skia    (21484): Shader compilation error
    D/skia    (21484): ------------------------
    D/skia    (21484):    1 #version 310 es
    D/skia    (21484):    2 
    D/skia    (21484):    3 in highp vec4 sk_FragCoord_Workaround;
    D/skia    (21484):    4 precision mediump float;
    D/skia    (21484):    5 precision mediump sampler2D;
    D/skia    (21484):    6 out mediump vec4 sk_FragColor;
    D/skia    (21484):    7 uniform sampler2D uTextureSampler_0_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):    8 in highp vec2 vTextureCoords_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):    9 flat in highp int vTexIndex_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   10 in mediump vec4 vinColor_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   11 void main() {
    D/skia    (21484):   12     mediump vec4 outputColor_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   13     mediump vec4 outputCoverage_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   14     {
    D/skia    (21484):   15         outputColor_Stage0 = vinColor_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   16         mediump vec4 texColor;
    D/skia    (21484):   17         {
    D/skia    (21484):   18             texColor = texture(uTextureSampler_0_Stage0, vTextureCoords_Stage0);
    D/skia    (21484):   19         }
    D/skia    (21484):   20         outputCoverage_Stage0 = texColor;
    D/skia    (21484):   21     }
    D/skia    (21484):   22     {
    D/skia    (21484):   23         sk_FragColor = outputColor_Stage0 * outputCoverage_Stage0;
    D/skia    (21484):   24     }
    D/skia    (21484):   25 }
    D/skia    (21484):   26 
    D/skia    (21484): Errors:
    D/skia    (21484): ERROR: The GPU does not support this version of OpenGL ES, try an older version
```

Face this issue in Flutter Android studio when install in device, some install successfully and works fine, but some installed successfully but show black screen.

Please guide, Thanks

Device Info in attach image

[image: Device Info]

Comment: Could you share what is your device?

Comment: device share...?

Comment: I mean your device model

Comment: Device info screen shot added

Comment: Alright, I think you are having the same issue as one user from my app which uses a Galaxy J6+ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36130 The bug is in Flutter 1.9.1 but not in 1.7.8. I think is fixed post 1.10 (but don't quote me on that)

Comment: In the end I solved it going back to Flutter version 1.7.8

Comment: Flutter 1.9.1 is stable, why that error occurs

Comment: To switch version you can do `flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4`and then `flutter run`

Comment: I know, I wonder same thing...

Comment: flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 not works to path sdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199569/discussion-between-martyns-and-engr-waseem-arain).

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to occur on Flutter 1.9, but has been resolved since 1.10 as mentioned in this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40150#issuecomment-564814106). Updating to the latest version of Flutter SDK should fix the issue.